# How to limit a "Rate This Application" fragment from constantly displaying

Tags: android-fragments, global-variables, android-dialogfragment, activity-finish

I want to have a fragment that asks a user to rate my application when they close it. The fragment works fine but can be annoying especially if it comes up the first few times the user closes the application.  I want them to use the application, say 5 times, before it appears.  How can this be done using a global holder?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with.  I'm sure everyone will tell me using globals is not the best way to do this.  But this worked for me.  In my Main Activity I put the following code:

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int theCount = globalHolder.getCounter();
    globalHolder.setCounter(theCount++);
    if (globalHolder.getStop() == 1) {

        finish();
    } else if (theCount == 5 || theCount == 10 || theCount == 25) {
        globalHolder.setCounter(theCount++);
        final DialogFragment rate = new RateMe();
        rate.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Rate");
    } else {
        globalHolder.setCounter(theCount++);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Now, let me explain this.  The first global is a counter.  I added this because I want to keep track of the number of times the user uses the app.  You will see why in a minute.  The counter initializes at 0.  So since the user is accessing the program for the first time I increment the counter.

The next line of code is put in so that I won't annoy users who don't want to rate the app or who have already agreed to rate it.  This is all you can do.  You cannot tell if they actually rated the app but you can determine if they push the button to do so.  So I have to assume that since they pressed the "Yes" button that they actually rated the app.  And now I want to stop displaying the fragment.  So I set up another global called....stop.  I set this global to "0" (for "no").  Yes, I used an int.  That was my choice.  You can use what you want.  So when the global is changed to "1" it increments the counter and then closes the program.

The 'else if' is where i set my limits of when I want the fragment to display.  It is set to display the fragment on the users 5th, 10th, and 25th use of the application only.  If they have not rated the app by the 25th use they are most likely not going to.  From this point the counter, again, is incremented (you will see why later) and the fragment is displayed on the counts above.

The next 'else' increments the counter and closes the program.

The fragment is:

```
public class RateMe extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle("Rate Me");
    builder.setMessage(R.string.Rate);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes, I Will", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).globalHolder.setStop(1);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=wolfEnterprisesLLC.motg&hl=en");
            Intent myAppLinkToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            myAppLinkToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            try {
                startActivity(myAppLinkToMarket);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), " unable to find market app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton("Please Do Not Ask Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).globalHolder.setStop(1);
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Not Now", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

- On positive click the global named "stop" is set to "1". From this point the user is sent to Play Store to rate the app.
- The "neutral" button which the user can push if they don't want to be asked again is also sets the global "stop" to "1". From here the program closes. Setting the global to "1", again, stops the fragment from appearing in the future.
- The Negative button, which is "Not Now", closes the program.  Looking back at the Main Activity remember the counter?  This is why I want the counter to continue.  So if the press the negative button it will still keep count and ask them again on the 10th and 25th use to rate the application if necessary.

And finally in my application class I added:

```
int stop;
 int counter;

public int getStop() {
    return stop;
}

public void setStop(int stop) {
    this.stop = stop;
}

public int getCounter() {
    return counter;
}

public void setCounter(int counter) {
    this.counter = counter;
}
```

So I help this helps someone.

:)